# Detecting corners of a geometry or mesh

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry, mesh, corner-detection

I'm looking for an algorithm to detect corners of a mesh:

[image: Mesh corners]

I'm having trouble defining what a corner is. Some might [suggest](https://www.mathopenref.com/vertex.html) that:

> ... a corner ... where lines meet ...

Is there any other definition I might need to consider?

Comment: You might want to think about the angle at which they meet - is there a corner if they meet at 180° ?  at 179° ?  And you might want to consider only 'corners' at the edge of the mesh.  And what if the two lines are actually arcs - is there a corner where a continuous curve is not differentiable ?  *etc*

Comment: Finding corners is a tricky business. Especially since your corners are rounded and only appear as corners on a higher level, not in the local neighborhood of a vertex. You might want to start by doing a search for feature extraction on meshes.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Do you know any fine reference on `feature extraction on meshes` which I might not be aware of? Thanks =)

Comment: I am not sure but I guess you could try to use some computational geometry libraries like CGAL which contains many algorithms that might help you.